# NSDateFormatter string with subseconds and timezone

Tags: objective-c

I have banged my head against this for too long now!
I have a string: 2012-09-27T18:00:00.000-04:00
I have a format: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
I get a null result converting the string.
Can someone help with the correct date format?

Comment: The basic problem is that NSDateFormatter will not handle the last ":" (the one in the timezone) in that style of timestamp, so you have to remove it somehow before attempting to parse the timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation for NSDateFormatter:

> The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35. The version of the standard varies with release of the operating system:
>
> Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0 use [version tr35-25].

Following that link:

> s     1..2    12  Second. Use one or two for zero padding.

In other words, `s` for seconds means only the integral part.

But right underneath that, there's:

> S     1..n    3456    Fractional Second - truncates (like other time fields) to the count of letters. (example shows display using pattern SSSS for seconds value 12.34567)

Then, the reason you aren't matching the timezone is that you're quoting the `Z`, so it matches a literal `Z` rather than a timezone format.

To match the ISO8601 timezone format you're seeing, the same documentation says you want ZZZZZ.

So, it looks like, at least for 10.8/iOS 6, you want:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZZZZZ"]
```

For earlier versions, you've got the links to the docs; you should be able to figure it out now.

Testing this (in Python, to save a few lines of code):

```
>>> import Cocoa
>>> df = Cocoa.NSDateFormatter.alloc().init()
>>> df.setDateFormat_("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.'SSSZZZZZ")
>>> print df.dateFromString_(2012-09-27T18:00:00.000-04:00')
2012-09-27 22:00:00 +0000
```